# How many statues are there?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes

The back of my trainer card shows that I have 96 "statue variants found". What does this mean? How many do I need to complete the "statue-dex"?

*Gotta mine 'em all!*

Answer (score 4):

That number is how many unique statues you own. Most statues also come as "color" statues (green with a shiny sparkle next to their name, found in Gorgeous Boxes), which also count.

By referencing [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/brilliantdiamondshiningpearl/statues.shtml), I found that the full statue-dex should have **529** total (306 of which are color — better fill up your Diglett meter and mine!). Getting every statue ultimately requires the National Dex.